# .NET Core 2.1 DbContext ObjectDisposedException Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm making an n-tier MVC application using .NET Core 2.1 and Entity Framework. There is also a hosted MQTT queue on which my application listens as a client. I also make use of Dependency Injection. This works perfectly, until a message is pushed to the queue and I want to save that message to the db. Once that happens I get following `ObjectDisposedException` error message:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. Object name: 'xxxDbContext'.

I can click continue, after which the application just continues to work. He only throws the exception on the first message received from the queue. Every other action with the controllers/managers/repositories works just fine. My code is as follows:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<xxxDbContext>();

    services.AddDbContext<xxxDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));

    // Some identity configuration omitted here

    services.AddScoped<IIdeationRepository, IdeationRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IIdeationManager, IdeationManager>();
    // Some other DI configuration omitted as well.
}

public Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    // Start MQTT
    var broker = new MqttBroker(serviceProvider.GetService<IIdeationManager>(),
        serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>());

    // On application exit terminate MQTT to make sure the connection is ended properly
    applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => broker.Terminate());

    // Some default http pipeline code omitted
}
```

MqttBroker.cs

```
public MqttBroker(
    [FromServices] IIdeationManager ideationManage,
    [FromServices] IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _ideationManager = ideationManager;
    _configuration = configuration;

    Initialize();
}

    // Some code where I just parse the message and on receive send it to the
    // ideation manager, this just works so I omitted it.
}
```

The manager just sends it directly to the repository, where the error message occurs.

Repository.cs

```
private xxxDbContext ctx;

public IdeationRepository(xxxDbContext xxxDbContext)
{
    this.ctx = xxxDbContext;
}

// This method crashes with the error
public IdeationReply ReadIdeationReply(int id)
{
    return ctx
        .IdeationReplies
        .Include(r => r.Votes)
        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.IdeationReplyId == id);
}
```

DbContext.cs

```
public class xxxDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Ideation> Ideations { get; set; }
    // Some more dbsets omitted

    public CityOfIdeasDbContext(DbContextOptions<CityOfIdeasDbContext> options) 
        : base (options)
    {
        CityOfIdeasDbInitializer.Initialize(this, dropCreateDatabase: false);
    } 

    // In configuring I just create a logger, nothing special

    // In OnModelCreating I just setup some value converters for other tables
    // than the ones I need here

    internal int CommitChanges()
    {
        if (delaySave)
        {
            int infectedRecords = base.SaveChanges();       
            return infectedRecords;
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "No UnitOfWork present, use SaveChanges instead");
    }
}
```

I've read [this](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/12/22/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext/) but none of these situations seem to apply to me. And when I print the stacktrace in `Dispose()` it happens in the `Main()` method, so it doesn't really help me.

Anyone an idea how to solve or where I can search to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where do you inject `IdeationRepository` and how you use it, show us services/repo registrations in `Startup.cs` too

Comment: More likely than not, you're implementing `IDisposable` and disposing of the context, even though it's being injected. That's just a guess, because you haven't posted the full code for anything here. If that is the case, stop. You should only dispose of things *owned* by the class, i.e. it news them up explicitly. If it's injected, the class doesn't own it and therefore should not dispose of it.

Comment: @ingvar updated question. Thanks for your reaction.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for your reaction. I don't ever call Dispose() explicitly in my code.

Comment: may be you have `using` somewhere? It will call `Dispose()`

Comment: Will changing `AddScoped` to `AddTransient` in your code help?

Comment: Except from using to import a namespace I don't use that keyword. I know what you mean but I don't use that construct here.

Comment: I changed the repository and manager to Transient instead of Scoped, but I still get the error. I don't think I can change the DbContext add? I even tried by switching addIdentity and addDbContext from place, but no luck.

Comment: Are you using Unit of Work pattern? Also, where does `System.ObjectDisposedException` occur, show us this method code

Comment: I don't use UoW yet, but I'm planning to. This error occurs in the repository ReadIdeationReply() method, on the ctx obj.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191043/discussion-between-ingvar-and-jc97).

Comment: Please add the full stack trace (of the exception and *all* inner exceptions) to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IServiceProvider` instance that's passed into `Configure` is *scoped*, which means that it gets disposed by the framework after `Configure` completes - any of the *scoped* services that it creates are also disposed during this process.

In your example, you're requesting an instance of `IIdeationManager` (which is *scoped*) and then attempting to use that in your `MqttBroker` class (which is, effectively, a *singleton*). By the time you attempt to use your implementation of `IIdeationManager`, the *scoped* instance of `CityOfIdeasDbContext` that was created and hooked up by DI has been disposed and so an `ObjectDisposedException` exception is thrown.

In order to resolve this, you can employ a general pattern that gets used when a singleton needs access to a scoped service: Create a scope, resolve the service, use the service and then dispose of the scope. Loosely, that would look a little bit like this:

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var ideationManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IIdeationManager>();

    // Do something with ideationManager.
}

// scope and all created disposable services have been disposed.
```

When you request an implementation of `IIdeationManager`, the DI system sees that (ultimately) it needs a scoped `CityOfIdeasDbContext` and creates one for you. Once `scope` is disposed, this `CityOfIdeasDbContext` instance is also disposed.

In order for this to work in your example, your `MqttBroker` can take an instance of `IServiceProvider` into its constructor and use that for creating the scope I've shown above (it can still take `IConfiguration` as-is given that that itself is a singleton).

The `IServiceProvider` instance that should be passed into the `MqttBroker` class should *not* be the `IServiceProvider` that is passed into `Configure` - this is already scoped and, as I've described, will be cleaned up after `Configure` completes, which is really the issue you've started out with. For this, use `app.ApplicationServices`, which is the root provider and is not scoped.

Comment: Works perfectly. The only thing now is that I create the MQTTBroker using new, not via DI: var broker = new MqttBroker(Configuration, app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceProvider>());  Reason of this is that I didn't find how to add this serviceProvider instead of the one of configure. Thanks for effort and this solution!

Comment: also, scope.GetService ... should be scope.ServiceProvider.GetService :)

Comment: Cool - thanks for the update (I've fixed the answer). You should be able to pass `app.ApplicationServices` directly into your `MqttBroker`, I think - Have you tried that?

Comment: Not automatically via DI it seems, I'm currently just using new but if there is a possibility to do it cleaner via DI it would be nice, but not a must have ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was faced same problem before also I was trying to dispose dbcontext object like .net classic layered structure repository design pattern cases but in .net core enough to make it scoped resolves problem. Because it dispose for each request so you dont need to dispose dbcontext manually. In addition, adddbcontext method in IServiceCollection implements it scoped as default. [Reference](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html)